# Set the action flag based on different scenarios in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to set the action flag based on the createdDate and Not used flag

I tried different solution from Google but couldn't find any relevant OR that fulfills the requirement. Can anyone help me with the Excel formula for the below scenarios.

Scenario 1.

[image]

If the master data columns have the same name, and all of them have Not Used flag, then we will set the "Keep" in the Action flag for the masterdata which is created on the latest date and Delete flag for the one which was created previously.

Scenario 2

[image]

If the master data have same names, 1 has Not used flag and the other one has "Used" flag then we will have the "Keep" flag for the one which is "Used" and the delete flag for the one which is not used, irrespective of date.

Scenario 3.

[image]

If master data have same names, both have Used flag, then we will have the "Keep" flag for the one which is created on the latest date and "Delete and Replace" action for the one which was created previously.

Scenario 4.

[image]

If the masterdata column has the same name, there are 2 used flag and 1 not used, then:

1. “Not used” will have the Delete action.
2. “Used” with the latest date will have the Keep action.
3. “Used” with the previous date will have the Delete and Replace Action Flag

Note:

1. Keep Flag will always be assiged to the Latest date masterdata
2. The number of masterdata may differ but I have used 2 or 3 for a reference

[image]

I want the above scenarios to achieve in Excel file. Please do assist me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The images will load when we click on it. Any inconvenience is regretted.

Comment: Show us what you tried, using `=IF()`, `=AND()`, `=OR()` and/or `=MATCH()` :-)

Comment: @Dominique -> I tried the below using conditional formatting in excel but it only works for Used and Not used flag scenario:

=AND($B1<>"", $B1=AGGREGATE(14, 7, B:B/($A$1:$A$9999=$A1), 1))

As I have multiple scenarios, the above solution breaks and I dont get the expected result. Hence any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Dominique -> Could you please help me with the Excel conditional formatting formula. It would be really helpful for me. Thanks in advance